# Symfony2 How access the months of this field from the Controller file

Tags: symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm

I have a field in a database table "dateinscription" of type "datetime"
I want to access the months of this field from the Controller file

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we supposed that you have an entity user as exemple in wish you have dateinscription attribute you need to get the user object from database like this in your controller:

```
//get the entity manager
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
//get your object : we supposed that dateinscription is an attribute from user entity
$user = $em->getRepository(YouFolder/UserBundle/Entity/User)->find(Id of the user);
//get inscription date
$dateinscription = $user->getDateInscription();
//get Month as string exemple 06
$month = $dateinscription->format('m');
```